# Gmail SMTP server: different password from the one used by the owner?

Tags: email, server, gmail, smtp

Im going to use a Gmail email address as an SMTP server. So I need the email password. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server

**The problem**: my customer doesn't want to give the email password, since I could check his emails..

Any way to configure a gmail SMTP server to use with a different password from the one that my customer uses to check his emails?

Comment: (I think you'll need to setup another Gmail account for this purpose?) There's also the "problem" of where you store this password, as it could also end being the weakest link in the customer's security.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you ask them to:

1. Setup another Gmail account and let you know the password
2. Configure to send from the newly created Gmail as the original address (See: [Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en))

Hope this helps :-)